# how to draw amchart pie chart using dynamic data(JSON)

Tags: angularjs, pie-chart, amcharts, donut-chart

i get data in JSON

```
{"Excellent":"5","NeedsImprovement":"14","Average":"9"}
```

How can i draw that JSON using AmCharts Pie chart / donut chart with angular-js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var data = JSON.parse(JSON_TEXT);
var dataProvider = [];

for(var key in data) {
  dataProvider.push({
    value: data[key],
    title: key,
  });
}


var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "none",
  "dataProvider": dataProvider,
  "titleField": "title",
  "valueField": "value",
  "labelRadius": 5,
  "radius": "42%",
  "innerRadius": "60%",
  "labelText": "[[title]]"
});
```

and for updating data you should do

```
chart.dataProvider = newSetOfDataArray;
chart.validateData();
```